# Not able to update nested objects in Stripe API either through postman or python stripe client

Tags: postman, stripe-payments

I am trying to update some fields by hitting the post request in stripe api.
But I am unable to update/access nested or complex json objects.

For example:-

I am able to update any field inside metadata object/dictionary or any other field such as email etc:-

```
{

"delinquent": false,
"description": "5f3a250ac1eaa40f0f8eaf7e",
"discount": null,
"email": "rahul.gunkar+t1@autodesk.com",
"invoice_prefix": "784B4E6D",

"livemode": false,
"metadata": {
    "Address_Line1": "Pune test 2",
    "Address_City": "random city 2",
    "Address_State": "random state 2",
    "Address_PostalCode": "random code 2",
    "Address_Country": "random country 2"
}
```

But I am not able to update any of the fields present in the sources object as it is nested, please refer the code below:-

```
{"sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "card_1HblKNKg447shOihGrpTMIGL",
            "object": "card",
            "address_city": null,
            "address_country": null,
            "address_line1": null,
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_line2": null,
            "address_state": null,
            "address_zip": null,
            "address_zip_check": null,
            "brand": "Visa",
            "country": "US",
            "customer": "cus_IC9dEzwYVKwLqw",
            "cvc_check": "pass",
            "dynamic_last4": null,
            "exp_month": 11,
            "exp_year": 2022,
            "fingerprint": "UTr7HATsezaxlGkF",
            "funding": "credit",
            "last4": "4242",
            "metadata": {},
            "name": null,
            "tokenization_method": null
        }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_IC9dEzwYVKwLqw/sources"
}
```

}

I want to update fields like **address_city** etc.

Please refer the screenshot attached for more details:-
[Attached image of the json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV21y.png)

Comment: You need to post the code that is doing the update. The json file are just that, a file... Is the code that changes values in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a linked object/resource you need to use the API specific to that resource. For example, if you want to update the address information on the card in your example (card_1HblKNKg447shOihGrpTMIGL) you would do so using the Cards API as documented here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/update

A cURL request for this my look something like:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_IC9dEzwYVKwLqw/sources/card_1HblKNKg447shOihGrpTMIGL \
  -u sk_test_replace_with_your_secret_key: \
  -d address_city=Toronto \
  -d address_country=CA
```

For hash properties like `metadata` on objects you can update them by specifying the key and value in an update request. Say for example you wanted to add/update the `Some_Key` key in a Customer's `metadata` you would do so as follows:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_IC9dEzwYVKwLqw \
  -u sk_test_replace_with_your_secret_key: \
  -d "metadata[Some_Key]"=xyz
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update

Comment: thanks mate, I got my answer..so in order to update the complex objects I need to consider primary key as well in the api endpoint..

Comment: In a sense yes, but it's more so using the right API endpoint. When updating a resource I'd first check the update method for that resource in the API (e.g., https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update). If the docs don't list the property in the update method then that means that any linked objects have their own separate endpoint for updating them.